# Multiple currency error in Paypal sandbox

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am integrating Paypal checkout Api in my php site. But every time the order is failing and its showing multiple currency error.

The payment scenario is as follows:

`Seller a/c is USD`

`Buyer can pay in 3 currencies GBP, EUR, USD`

Every time when a buyer visits the site, my app detects their country and initialize PAYPAY with the relevant Currency.

Please suggest some solution

Comment: What you have done to say you have error?

Comment: I use Paypal NVP API. When the payment is made... Paypal sandox send response to my app. I further send the response to my mail and there it shows the Multiple Currency error.

Comment: what currency you are passing? I think you are passing more currency code to the paypal. please check the data you are passing to paypal website and pick the value for currency cod in that

Comment: Yes you are right you just print and check all the data you are sending to paypal before sending to them. Also check that currency_code is current and updated one given by paypal.

Comment: @VinothBabu Everything works well with USD.... but for other currencies it shows error

Comment: @VinothBabu Since my buyer a/c is in USD... will it only accept USD??

Comment: Yup i think so. For which country the paypal account belongs to it will work on that own currency code. I hope so